# ElasticBeanstalk key pair update

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

You can change an EC2 instance key pair when deploying with ElasticBeanstalk, which is great. EB supposedly terminates current instance and launches a new one with whatever key pair you specified. So I created a new key pair (AWS console), downloaded a new *.pem file, updated my machine to use the key pair in EB. All good so far, EB re-launched the server. One little issue with this is that I can't ssh into the instance using the latest *.pem file. This is what I get (and I did do "chmod 400" on the pem file):

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 52.1.*.* [52.1.*.*] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file mypem.pem type -1
debug1: identity file mypem.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 6b:5a:e2:0c:c5:98:ff:34:6e:c6:2c:84:ea:a0:88:0f
debug1: Host '52.1.*.*' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/sergey.novgorodsky/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: mypem.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Could it be an EB issue? Any ideas?

Comment: More likely configuration issue. You should see something like `Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/myoung/.ssh/key.pem` but that's not there. There are other weird errors like `Roaming not allowed by server`. What does your /etc/ssh_config look like for lines 20+? My guess is that it's not correct.

Comment: "Roaming not allowed by server" This is a security hole in your client. See http://superuser.com/a/826734/54530.